# Is there a mathematical explanation for why there occur bound states if the effective potential falls below zero?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, potential

Usually in physics textbooks, if the effective potential of the radial schroedinger equation
$$-\frac{d^2}{dr^2}u(r) + \frac{\ell(\ell+1)}{r^2}u(r) + V(r)u(r) = E u(r)$$
falls below zero in some subinterval $I\subset(0,\infty)$, a (physical) argument is made for the existence of bound states.

Is there actually a way to mathematically proof the existence of bound states in this case?

Comment: Are you asking for generic $V(r)$ or specifically with $V(r)$ the electrostatic potential?

Comment: actually i'm most interested in the yukawa and the hulthen potential. for the coulomb potential (=electrostatic potential?) i think i could explicitely write down the wave functions. :)

Comment: Not a mathematical proof but if you spatially discretise this equation and solve the resultant matrix, the number eigenvalues will give you the number of bound states.

Answer (score 0):

There need not be any bound state if $V(r)$ is chosen appropriately. Even a potential $V(r)=-V_0$ for $r<R$, $V(r)=0$ for $r>R$ will have no bound states if the potential is sufficiently shallow: see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_potential_well#Spherical_cavity).

Comment: You are right. I'll edit the question so that it makes more sense. I specifically had potentials in mind with a first order pole at $r=0$ which are continuous and vanish at infinity.